# Browsers' autocompleting

Tags: browser, autocomplete

I have a search on site. It is simple text input with submit button. I realized custom autocompleting from database.

It's ok but browsers caching all my search queries (I mean strings that I searched). And drop down browser's autocomplete from cache. I don't need it, how to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```